# How to strictly parse a date with only a year and a week number when the first day of this week is in the previous year?

Tags: java, parsing, date, calendar

My goal is to have a strict parsing (and forbid dates like '98/99' for example). However, the following code raises a `java.text.ParseException` with the message *Unparseable date: "98/01"*:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/ww");
sdf.setLenient(false);
sdf.parse("98/01");
```

This is indeed for the [first week of 1998](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html?year=1998&month=1&country=5), which starts on a Thursday. However, the parsing of a week always returns the date of the **first day** of this week. In that case, it would be *12/29/1997*. And this is why an exception is raised.

It seems this problem comes from the `GregorianCalendar` class and more specifically from the `computeTime()` method which checks if the original fields match the fields externally set when the parsing is **not lenient**:

```
if (!isLenient()) {
  for (int field = 0; field < FIELD_COUNT; field++) {
    if (!isExternallySet(field)) {
      continue;
    }

    if (originalFields[field] != internalGet(field)) {
      // Restore the original field values
      System.arraycopy(originalFields, 0, fields, 0, fields.length);
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(getFieldName(field));
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a bug? I think parsing *1998/01* should indeed return *12/29/1997* and not raise any exception. However, do you know how to make the parsing returns *01/01/1998* instead (which would be the first day of the week in the specified year)?

Comment: Did you try "Yoda time" lib? I personally haven't, but I heard it's superior to JDK date/time classes.

Comment: I did try [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), but I was not able to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for you (you need the library joda time for this):

```
public static Date parseYearWeek(String yearWeek) {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yy/ww").parseDateTime(yearWeek);

    if (dateTime.getWeekOfWeekyear() == 1 && dateTime.getMonthOfYear() == 12) {
        dateTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/mm").parseDateTime((dateTime.getYear() + 1) + "/01");
    }

    return dateTime.toDate();
}
```

Comment: It's perfect. I still take advantage of the `SimpleDateFormat` parsing but use your approach whenever a `ParseException` is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Thursday as a reference, subtract 3 days to calculate the date of Monday. 
ISO 8601 definition of week 1 is the first week where Thursday occurs.
This will eliminate the compensating code.
The code below will find the Monday in a week, even if Monday is in the "previous" year.

```
String yearWeek = "201301";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyywwEEE").withLocale(Locale.US);
DateTime mondayInWeek= fmt.parseDateTime(yearWeek + "Thu").minusDays(3);// ISO 8601 def of week 1 is first week where Thursday occurs
System.out.println(mondayInWeek);
```